# How can I check if a string already contains a character in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to check in my app, if there is already a `-` character in the `textField`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Need more explanation of your question? Actually where do you want to check when keyboard shows or where ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contains()` method

```
let myString = "test"
if myString.contains("e"){
   let index = myString.index(of: "e")
   myString.remove(at: index!)
}
```

p.s you can get `myString` from `textField.text`

Comment: Yeah this works. Do you know, how I can delete a - when it is in the textfield?

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

```
var yourTextFieldString: String = textField.text

yourTextFieldString.contains("-")
```

It returns a Bool.